# COncrete5 : Query string doesnt work when not logged in on Dashboard

Tags: query-string, block, concrete5

I'm working with a custom Block which involved a query string. When I'm logged in as Administrator, everything works perfect unfortunately when I'm logged out, I my query string string is shoing on the address bar but the page is not displaying the correct information.

Sample query string:http://c5.demop_site.com/calendar/?date=2012-12...

calendar segment is being generated by a custom function from my controller which is written below.

http://c5.demop_site.com/getCurrentUrl(); ?>/?date=2012-12

```
public function getCurrentUrl(){
  global $c;
  $nh = Loader::helper('navigation');
  $cpl = $nh->getCollectionURL($c); 
  return $cpl;
}
```

The function also doesnt work when I'm not logged in, so I I'm wondering if this is the cause of the error on my query string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions for that page?

Comment: Hi thank you for responding on my concern, I trired to change the permission of the page and let All User Group View the site and it changed a little bit because My function to get the current url from my controller is already working when I'm not logged in.

Unfortunately, query string doesnt work yet :(.

Comment: Well, it looks like I just tried to answer that question here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613994/concrete5-can-i-use-get-variable-for-query-string-on-regular-page). Let me know how that goes.